# MySQL : Selecting alternative field if given field is empty

Tags: mysql

I wonder if is it possible to run mysql command which can select an alternative field if the first given field is empty, on the same table.

Example : I have table called "posts" which have "intro" and "content". In the same statement I would like to select as a result "content" if "intro" is empty, but not having both in the result array.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function:

```
SELECT IF(LENGTH(intro)>0, intro, content) 
FROM posts
```

Or you can test for `NULL` if you mean that empty is `NULL`

Comment: +1: `CASE` would be a viable alternative, but the `LENGTH` keyword isn't supported on all other databases (Oracle, Postgres but not SQL Server - have to use `LEN`) which makes query portability almost moot.

Comment: IF(LENGTH(TRIM(intro))>0, intro, content) to ensure that nobody saved few '  ' spaces

Answer (score 20):

Coalesce is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT COALESCE(intro, content) AS column1
FROM table
```

Assuming intro is null and not a zero length string.

Answer (score 3):

There two potential ways. When way is with a case statement.

```
Select case when field1 <> '' then field2 else field1 end
```

or you you can use coalesce.

```
select coalesce(field1, field2)
```

Comment: There are a more than two. You have IF, IFNULL, CASE WHEN, CASE fiel1 WHEN, and COALESCE off the top of my head.

And "<> '' won't work in the obvious case when "empty" means NULL.